# ASP.NET Core Web API : how to use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices to send logs to Blob Storage

Tags: asp.net, azure, logging

I have an ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API. My API is hosted on Azure. I am trying to configure logging to blobs using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices`.

I have followed many tutorials but no matter what I do, logging will not show up on the azure blob.

I found this when searching:  https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28486

However I have found many people on youtube and tutorials that are not having this issue.

I also tried connecting to the Blob Container using the GUI Visual Studio, which added these lines of code:

```
builder.Services.AddAzureClients(clientBuilder =>
{
    clientBuilder.AddBlobServiceClient(builder.Configuration["MyConnection:blob"], preferMsi: false);
    clientBuilder.AddQueueServiceClient(builder.Configuration["MyConnection:queue"], preferMsi: false);
});
```

I tried adding the connections in the `appsettings.json` but that did not work either.

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if this is actually broken. I would appreciate any help or better ideas for logging.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar issues, so as an alternative you can use below process:

Firstly created a `Asp.Net Core Web Api` and below are the lines of code:

**`Controller.cs:`**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication8.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Secret Rithwik");
            _logger.LogDebug("Debug message in Get Rithwik");
            _logger.LogWarning("Warning Message Rithwik");
            _logger.LogError("Error message in Get Rithwik");
            _logger.LogCritical("Critical Rithwik");

            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();

            
        }
    }
}
```

**`csproj:`**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices" Version="7.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**`Program.cs:`**

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(ITelemetryChannel), new ServerTelemetryChannel());
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**`appsettings.json:`**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=1f694869-7-7e6ac60e1b58;IngestionEndpoint=https://centralindia-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://centralindia.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  }
}
```

**`Now in Application Insights:`**

[image]

Now I have sent these logs to storage account using  Diagnostic settings like below:

[image]

Then :

[image]

**`Now after some time check the logs in storage account:`**

[image]

Here, I firstly sent the logs to app insights and then to storage account.

Comment: Well I figured out my issue, for some reason the logging was not working using while testing through swagger.  When I tried from the actual device, the logging works. However, I am getting an absorbent amount of logging....for some reason I am seeing a lot of EF core logging that I am not doing.  I am not sure why,

Comment: How long did it take for the logs to show up in the storage account?

Comment: And how do you have so many diagnostic dimensions available? All I have are "Function Application Logs" under logs and "AllMetrics" under Metrics

Comment: It took  around 1 hour to show up